# Modify Control Order in VC14 Build Menu Bar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

You can customize the control order of the build toolbar in Tools->Customize->Commands and settings Menu Bar: to Build.

[image]

The changes are remembered in the Customize dialog after closing but are not applied to Visual Studio - Right-clicking on a project in the solution explorer displays a Build menu bar without the modified control order.

Does anybody know if the order can be permanently modified, and if so, how to apply it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Context Menu' refers to the right-click options tab. In particular the 'Class View Context Menus' and 'Project and Solution Context Menus' refer to the options created on the solution browser.